# Getting error msg as WebResource.axd?d=xxxxxxx Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working in asp.net and while clicking on a asp.net Button I am getting an error messsage of

```
 WebResource.axd?d=xxxxx 
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
        at HTMLFormElement.WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit [as submit] (WebResource.axd?d=xxxxx
        at Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager.__doPostBack [as _originalDoPostBack] (COMGeneration.aspx:46)
        at Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_doPostBack [as _doPostBack]
```

while trying to click a `asp:button` in the console and the server call is not made. In Sources tab of browser the error is at the `theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONY'].value = window.pageYOffset;` line of the following code.

```
 function WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit() {
     if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
            theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONY'].value = window.pageYOffset;
            theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONX'].value = window.pageXOffset;
        }
```

Please tell me what can be done to fix this issue. Why I am getting error in the `WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit` function while I am not explicitly using it.While other buttons are working fine in the same page, why I am facing this issue at a particular place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the asp.net button and the input textboxes inside a content template of update panel and now the button is making the server call fine.

Comment: could it be due to a conflict with JS files ?